# Sequential Consistency

Tags: parallel-processing, distributed-computing

Is the following sequential consistent

P1: W(x)1 R(x)1    -----------------------                 R(x)1

P2: W(x)2  -------------          R(x)2  R(x)1

P3: W(x)3 R(x)3         ----------------------             R(x)1

I believe this is sequentially consistent as the program order is meet by the individual processors

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a sequentially consistent trace.

For it to be sequentially consistent, there should exist an equivalent *legal* trace in which operations of each process are executed in its program order. And a trace is *legal* when it's sequential and each read to register X returns the last written value.

We can construct a *legal* trace, but operations of P2 and P3 in it would not match their program order (reads that return 1 had to be reordered before writes):

```
P1: W(X, 1)
P1: R(X) → 1
P1: R(X) → 1
P2: R(X) → 1
P3: R(X) → 1
P2: W(X, 2)
P2: R(X) → 2
P3: W(X, 3)
P3: R(X) → 3
```

Trying to satisfy both properties we find that it's not possible:

```
// it doesn't matter where we start really: P1, P2 or P3
// (but with P2 and P3 the seq. consistent part of the trace would be even shorter)
// let's go with P1 
P1: W(X, 1)

// now the next read has to see X=1 so the trace remains legal
P1: R(X) → 1
// and again
P1: R(X) → 1

// no more P1's operations,
// have to chose first op in either P1's or P2's program order
// let's go with P2
P2: W(X, 2)

// now the next read has to see X=2 so the trace remains legal
P2: R(X) → 2 // great!

// at this point there's no operation that would keep the trace legal
// except P3's W(X, 3)
P3: W(X, 3)

// there's only three reads left and the next one should see X=3
P3: R(X) → 3 // yay!

// but the last two reads ruin everything
P2: R(X) → 1 // not seq. consistent! (because isn't legal)
P3: R(X) → 1 // again, not seq. consistent!
```